# SalesForce SSO with GoodData

Tags: gooddata

**Getting Unable to Load Error**
We are tryed to integrate GoodData dashboard to saleforce using SSO(Single sign On).
We did all the setting for a salesforce user. This user is also a member in GoodData plateform and user can login Goodata and Saleforce with the same username and password.
But in salesforce tab showing error message like "**Unable to Load**".
Thanks.

Comment: Can you double check that the username is same both in Salesforce and in GoodData? Is the user setup with Salesforce SSO Provider?

Answer (score 3):

Prerequisite for GD-Salesforce SSO integration is that:

- GD Contact email = SF login email

Please be aware here, the GD user has 2 properties regarding to emails. 1. Login email, 2. Contact email. Please ensure that your Contact email is the same as SF login email, Login email can differs. See definition of GD user entity here:

```
{
"accountSetting":{
"login": "user@login.com",
"password":"PASSWORD",
"email":"contact@email.com",
"verifyPassword":" PASSWORD ",
"firstName":"FirstName",
"lastName":"LastName",
"ssoProvider":"SSO-PROVIDER"
 }
}
```

- Your GD user has to have correct ssoProvider set. Correct ssoProvider for Salesforce integration is always "salesforce.com".

Another thing is a source of your SF tab which can be in two different formats:

- Webtab
- VisualForce page

You can find the appropriate tab source within GD through "Embed" dialog. Simply copy and paste the link provided to SF tab as a page source.

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Jan Kucera

Comment: Slight correction here - it is the Login email that has to match the email in salesforce, so: GD Login email = SF User email.  

From GoodData Support, "So, The GoodData user ID for in your GoodData organization must match the user email from Salesforce."